# C reading a file char by char and displaying it on the console

Tags: c

In the following code, I am trying to read a file char by char and display each char on the console:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
int main(){

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c ",(char)c );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I got the following error:

[image]

Can someone help me solving this issue?

Comment: Please pick one language, not two. That said, check how `fopen()` signals failures.

Comment: Everything is in the error message: there is an assertion that prevent fgetc to process if the stream is NULL. You need to check the return of fopen

Comment: Note: The cast here: `printf("%c ",(char)c );` is unneccessary

Comment: Don't post images of text. Past the error message as text in the question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must check the result of fopen. The pointer file is NULL because the opening failed.

```
file = fopen("input.txt", "r");

if (file == NULL)
{
    //error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The message on the popup: *Expression: (stream != NULL)* is the key.
Check the results of `fopen()` before using the returned stream `file`.

As an alternate to `fgetc()` you might also consider using:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%c",&c) == 1)
```

or

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%c",&c) != EOF)
```

`fgetc` returns an EOF. `fscanf()` returns the number of input items assigned, or EOF if there was a failure before any conversion takes place.

Comment: Even if `fscanf(fp,"%c",&c) != EOF`, the case where `fscanf(fp,"%c",&c) == 0` calls for error handling

Comment: @sunqingyao For `%c`, will `fscanf` return 0? I think that I read `!= EOF` is enough for `%c` somewhere.

Comment: _[fscanf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm)_ returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.  @CoolGuy, I think you are right.

Comment: @CoolGuy You're right